# Dynamically change Text value

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, globalization, multilingual

I'm trying to implement a multilingual WPF application, I've a problem and I don't know how should I deal with this situation. Let's say I have 2 `.Resx` files and a `TextBlock` element which its `Text` property is bind to a class responsible to translate to a appropriate value by given key. They are work fine in run-time, but working with them is too hard in design-time because they don't able to get values from resources in design-time and `Text`'s values are always empty. I'm curious how can I change Text property of `TextBlock` element at design-time.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization

Answer (score 0):

you can visit this post

[Multilingual WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327840/multilingual-wpf-application/11328578#11328578)